# Exporting to .pdf using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel SaveAs Error. but wihout save excel file

Tags: c#, excel

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelPDF = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook MyWorkbookPDF = excelPDF.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\range rules - Copia.xlsx");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet MyWorkSheetPDF;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range MyCell3PDF;

            MyWorkbookPDF.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Filename.PDF", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false, false,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Error: PDF fle damaged.
please help me!

Comment: Is this C++ or C#?  Definitely isn't C.

Comment: this is c++. sorry

Comment: You're saving an *Excel* file (Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal) with a `.PDF` extension. That's still an Excel file

Comment: PDF is a print format, not an editable document. Use the [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) method to save to PDF. Essentially, you're telling Excel to print the workbook to a PDF tile

Comment: Thanks it's correct, I used it